# MariaDB - Epoch date comparisons

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On MariaDB 10, I'm trying to work with dates, particularly whether the current date is within 7 days of a date stored in the database. A longtext column holds an Epoch datetime, which I convert into a date-only using `FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y')`, and it returns nicely like 11/03/2019 (UK time formatting). But if I try to use it in datediff using a second parameter like now(), datediff returns NULL - and PHPMyAdmin shows a `#1292 incorrect datetime value`. I've additionally tried adding `date_format` and `str_to_date` without any remedy, and plenty of reading through Stackoverflow and internet articles.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(column, '%d/%m/%Y') returns 11/03/2019

datediff(date_format(now(), '%d/%m/%Y'),FROM_UNIXTIME(column, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

returns NULL, whether I use date_format or not.

I've also tried moving the code to the where clause, but this returns a #1292 error as well : `WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') > curdate()`

Comment: The main problem is you are using a TEXT field to store a date. Stop doing that and you'll find lots of aspect about date handing so much easier. In your mess of functions keep track of what is returned i.e `date_format` returns text so why is that being passed to `datediff`. Don't try to get it into UK date format for comparison, use that for results only if you really must.

Comment: @danblack - sadly, it's not my schema so I can't change the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Using CAST to DATETIME got the database engine to recognise that it was a date, and then it was simpler from there.

```
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(column) as DATETIME)
```

Thanks to danblack